# 'The rpc server is unavailable' or 'access is denied' error when using Remote desktop Services Manager on Windows 7 (but mstsc.exe works!)

Tags: windows, windows-7, remote-desktop

I am trying to connect to a Windows XP workstation from a Windows 7 Ultimate workstation using Remote Desktop Services Manager.

I am able to do a Remote Desktop (mstsc.exe) session from the Win7 machine to the WinXP machine with no problem at all.
When running the Remote Desktops Admin (tsmmc.msc) too on a Windows XP box, I can also connect with no problem.
However, when I use the new Remote Desktop Services Manager on Windows 7 and try to connect, I get the error: "The rpc server is unavailable"

What could cause this?  Has there been some fundamental change in Remote Desktop Services Manager, does it connect in a different way somehow?

### Update #1

Turned off firewall on the Windows XP box and the "The rpc server is unavailable" error went away; so RDSM seems to be using an entirely new port/connection/service compared to mstsc.exe or the old Remote Desktops Admin tool.

**Now...** after disabling the firewall, I get a new error:
Access is Denied.

After doing some googling, I found some articles discussing this; basically, the error is very misleading - the actual problem is, if **either** side of the connection has dual monitors, and they are not **both** Win7 Ultimate, then you cannot connect using Remote Desktop Services Manager...the reason is, by default it uses the /multimon switch, and this switch requires a certain level of Windows license - and, there seems to be no way of changing this default (if anyone knows of a way to change this default, please post an answer or comment!).  Nice going Microsoft.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2rds/thread/4d06278f-e0f4-4f8e-a8e1-3697ee967ef4

http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Windows/Windows_7/Q_26225743.html

Comment: Have you had any success with this?  I've encountered this before.